# why custom theme properties not working [dart]?

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, flutter-theme

This is a custom theme code that I created in the main page.
It didnt work, but when I use it indivually with a specific widget it works

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:theme/homepage.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyApp({super.key});

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _MyAppState();
    }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
           ** theme: ThemeData(
                appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                fontFamily: "Sixtyfour"
            ),**
            home: Home(),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include more details about the `Home` and other page as well?

Answer (score -1):

Your  code mostly correct, but there is an issue with the placement of the theme property within the MaterialApp. The theme property should be placed directly under MaterialApp, not under debugShowCheckedModeBanner.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
        fontFamily: "Sixtyfour",
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

By placing the theme property directly under MaterialApp, it should apply the custom theme to the entire app, including the HomePage widget. Make sure there are no conflicts with other theme settings in your app that might override this custom theme.

Comment: I tried it & didn't work unfortunately